# Spring Cloud Server not importing centralized configuration from BitBucket/Gitlab

Tags: git, spring-boot, gitlab, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm trying to implement an example for Spring Cloud centralized configuration. I have my Spring Cloud server which gets the configurations from a git repository and send them to another app.
No problems if I use a **public Github repository**, but when I use a **Gitlab** or **Bitbucket** private repositories, I cannot get my new configurations loaded.

This is my server application.properties:

```
server.port=8888
#gitlab
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://gitlab.com/myusername/reponame
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=myusername
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=mypassword
```

I've also tried to specify the uri this way:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://gitlab.com/myusername/reponame.git
```

with no results.
The project in the repo is exacly the same of the one imported from my public Github repository (the one which works).

Another strange issue, regarding the Client which receives the configuration is that **@RefreshScope** doesn't work if put on **@SpringBootApplication** or if put on my **@RestController**, so I have to restart the Client application to let it get the new configurations.

Answer (score 1):

That's the correct config (double checked my own) so make sure that the username/password are correct by doing a git clone passing in the credentials:

```
git clone https://myusername:mypassword@gitlab.com/myusername/reponame
```

Also, the @RefreshScope doesn't poll for updated configurations.  You need to POST to the /refresh endpoint (which needs to be enabled)

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/refresh
```

Comment: with gitlab I've signed in using my github account, so using github password and the same public username even the clone fails. With bitbucket the git clone works, but it's not working in the application.properties. !! Thanks also for the second hint! Very useful.

Comment: I've set my password for gitlab, so now I sign in with no social account. It works for cloning, but no result for getting properties. I really don't understand the reason!